# React setState in .map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to made a hangman game in React.js and I have a function who take a random word among a list of word, I want to split this word and replace each letter by a "_ " but when I set the setState in the .map, it take only one "_" and not as many times as letters.

Someone can help me ?

```js
const words = [...this.state.wordList];

const length = words.length;

const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);

const word = this.state.wordList[random].word;

const splitedWord = word.split("");

splitedWord.map(( letter, index ) => {
  const hiddenLetter = letter.replace(/./, "_");

  this.setState({usedWord: hiddenLetter});
}
```

Comment: It'd be better to provide a working example of the whole component. Also that part of code you've provided has syntax error.

Comment: Hard to tell without the rest of your code, but if you want to replace all letters by `_`, you need to add a global flag to the regex: `letter.replace(/./g, "_");` (notice the `g`). But it makes little sense to call `setState` in a `.map`…

Comment: Why even use map when all you need is `_____`? Just create that string. Something like `const splittedWord = new Array(word.length + 1).join("_");` Then set the state to that.

Comment: In general it's not a good idea to `setState()` in every iteration of a loop. It's not efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are only getting one character replaced is because for each iteration you are replacing the **original** string, not the new one you generate in each loop. That being said, you shouldn't do it like that. As mentioned in the comments, using `setState()` in a loop is inefficient and unnecessary.

---

You already know that for the word `Orange` (6 letters) you want 6 `_`. As such, there is no need to iterate through each character and replace them one-by-one. Simply create a string of `_` with said length!

You can do this with:

```
new Array(word.length + 1).join("_");
```

You are now ready to put this in your state. In other words:

```
this.setState({usedWord: new Array(word.length + 1).join("_")});
```